# How to safely backport specific linux kernel commits to an older kernel using git

Tags: git, linux-kernel, commit

I'm currently on a stable 2.6.32 kernel. But I need certain fixes on 2.6.33 branch to be incorporated into this 2.6.32 kernel so that I can create a custom kernel for testing purposes. I can't apply the said fixes directly to the 2.6.32 source because they seem to have dependencies on other fixes.

Is there any safe way to incorporate *only* the fixes (and all their dependencies) I need into the 2.6.32 kernel with git to create a custom kernel?

Assuming there is a way to do the above, is there a way to track the fixes that have been applied to the custom kernel (i.e. track which commits have been applied to the 2.6.32 kernel to create the custom kernel source)?

Comment: What prevents you from using 2.6.33?

Comment: I'm told 2.6.33 might break certain things, so the solution would be to backport the required fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can isolate the individual commits, you can also cherry pick them (choose commits from another branch to commit to your branch).

Also, if you need better visualization of the trees [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) is the best I have seen so far.

Comment: Hmm thanks! I'll take a look at SmartGit to see if I can trace all the dependencies leading to the fix I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the merges done by Linus to his tree with git log. Then you can try to pull/merge those yourself. I am not sure though,as to how dependencies will be taken care of here.(IMO when you pull, they should be taken care of).

Comment: I'm not sure how to fetch/merge part of a branch up to a specific point. If i just pull the branch, wouldn't my kernel be effectively 2.6.33?